# XMLHttpRequest returns different progress event in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, xmlhttprequest

Trying to overcome the variable deficiencies of Flash's upload-to-server function - particularly not being able to track upload progress when cookies are required - I have decided to create a JavaScript function that does the upload and keeps track of the upload progress events.

Here it is:

```
window.you_animate = {
     objToString: function(obj) {
        var res = "{";
        for (var str in obj) {
            res += str +"=" + obj[str] + ",";
        }
        res += "}";
        return res;
    },

    upload: function(url, _files, _data, progressCb, successCb, errorCb) {
        alert("a,"+url);
        var fd = new FormData(),
            files = _files || [],
            data = _data || [],
            i;

        alert("b");
        for (i in data) {
            fd.append(i, data[i]);
        }

        alert("c");
        for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            alert(i+"/"+files.length+" file= "+you_animate.objToString(file));
            var blob = file.file || new Blob(file.data, {
                    type: file.type
                });
            alert("blob= "+you_animate.objToString(blob));

            fd.append(file.name, blob);
        }
        alert("d");
        var ajax_opts = {
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: fd,
            headers: {},
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            xhr: function() {
                alert("1");
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

                if (xhr.upload) {
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressCb, false);
                }

                return xhr;
            },
            success: successCb || $.noop,
            error: errorCb || $.noop
        };
        alert("2");
        $.ajax(ajax_opts);
        alert("3");
    },

    uploadProgress: {},

    // => _data = base64 binary
    uploadFromFlash: function(url, _files, _data) {
        alert("0");
        var uploadProcess = {};
        var uploadProcessID = "id" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000).toString();
        you_animate.uploadProgress[uploadProcessID] = uploadProcess;

        // workaround for Flash bug ("[]" in variable name)
        for (var str in _data) {
            _data["UploadCharacterForm["+str+"]"] = _data[str];
            delete _data[str];
        }

        alert("01");
        // base64 -> Blob-friendly stuff
        for (i = 0; i < _files.length; i++) {
            var file = _files[i];
            var binary = atob(file.data);
            var array = new Uint8Array(binary.length);
            for( var i = 0; i < binary.length; ++i ) { array[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i) }
            file.data = [array]; // NOTE : why "[array]" and not "array" ??
        }

        alert("02");
        you_animate.upload(url, _files, _data,
            function(progressEvent) {
                uploadProcess.progressEvent = progressEvent;
            },
            function(successEvent) {
                uploadProcess.successEvent = successEvent;
                uploadProcess = null;
            },
            function(errorEvent) {
                uploadProcess.errorEvent = errorEvent;
                uploadProcess = null;
            }
        );                  

        return uploadProcessID;
    },

    trackProcessID: function(id) {
        return you_animate.uploadProgress[id];
    },

    destroyProcessID: function(id) {
        delete you_animate.uploadProgress[id];
    },

    uploadForm: function(form, progressCb, successCb, errorCb) {
        var $form = $(form),
            action = $form.attr('action') + '?json';

        var data = $form.serializeArray().reduce(function(prev, curr){
            prev[curr.name] = curr.value; return prev;
        }, {} );

        var $files = $form.find('input[type=file]');
        var files = [];
        $files.each(function(index, node) {
            if (node.files[0]) {
                files.push({
                    name: node.name,
                    file: node.files[0]
                });
            }
        });

        you_animate.upload(action, files, data, progressCb, successCb, errorCb);
    }
};
```

**Question 1**: the progress event differs between **Chrome and Firefox**. The first returns `loaded` & `totalSize` (among lots of other stuff), while Firefox returns `loaded` & `total`!!!

Is there somewhere a specification for the returned progress event?!

**Question 2**: Internet Explorer 8 crashes right after alert("0") ! Maybe it doesn't like "[ ]" in the following line:

```
    _data["UploadCharacterForm["+str+"]"] = _data[str];
```

Anything to do about that?

Comment: IE8 does not support formData or blobs at all, so it crashing is no suprise. As for the progress event, it can differ between browsers, and it does.

Comment: @adeneo 1 - Are you talking about ALL IE versions? 2 - How can IE use XMLHttpRequest with large binaries and without Blob? 3 - So, is there a list of progress event properties returned by all "important" browsers?

Comment: I was talking about IE8, which you mentioned, but basically all IE have some issues with this, you can check support [**here**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2). IE8 doesn't do large binaries, older browsers generally don't ? And no, there probably is no definitive list, you'd have to search the web and see if someone else has documented this.